# Url issues in nodejs search and pagination

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web, pagination

I have a results page with pagination. Routes are as follows:

```
app.get("/results",function(req,res){
query= select * from courses where
// the following line adds search parameters from req.query to the sql query//
Object.keys(req.query.search).forEach(function(key){
            query+= key + " = "+ (req.query.search[key])

            })
conn.query(query,callback(){

....
....

...
res.render("results",{results,results})
})

)}
```

This code works fine at first but as soon as I click pagination buttons to move to second page , the `search_query` parameters do not pass to second page and `req.query.search` becomes `undefined` there for sending `undefined` results error.

Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your method does not send the `search_query` parameter but you can try this so you do not have problems with `undefined`.

```
app.get("/results/:id", function (req, res) {
    const { id } = req.params;

    // Now in this part you can use the value of the variable id for your query

    // Implementing my amazing query...
});
```

**¿What is the difference?**

Using this form we ensure we have a value that we can use for the page, so now our requests will be for example `http://localhost/results/14` where `14` can be my id that I use as a filter in the query.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Another thing is that would this also help if i have lets say multiple search parameters such as country department  from which I have to generate the query , and not all filters have to be filled always

Comment: If you want multiple parameters you must send them in the body of the request or as a query parameter.

Comment: @sabim If my answer was useful to you, you can accept it or qualify it so other users with a similar problem can find a solution faster.

Comment: Done mate. Thanks for the help